# Can DebugDiag be configured not to generate dumps for a scheduled IIS app pool recycle?

Tags: iis, application-pool, recycle, debugdiag

Our production application pools (IIS 8.0-8-5, .Net 4.5 integrated pipeline) are set to recycle daily, this is unlikely to change in the short term.

Is there a way to prevent a DebugDiag (2.2.0.14) creating a dump at this time and blowing out our disk storage?

Comment: It depends on how you configured it. Usually the crash rule only creates dumps when the process crashes, but it seems that you configured it to also create dumps when the process exits (during recycle). So that's something you should review yourself. BTW, DebugDiag rules should be disabled by default on a production system. Why do you leave it enabled always?

Comment: @LexLi I don't believe there is a way to configure it not to dump on process exit, at least there is no option that I have seen, could you be more explicit?  We have crashes that can't be reproduced in our testing or integration environments, hence the dumps on production, but the same issue would apply regardless of environment.

Comment: If you have to leave the rule enabled, then your only chance is to set a limit on user dump count, https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/asiatech/2014/01/09/debug-diagnostic-2-0-creating-a-rule-in-crash-mode/ and then manually remove useless dumps from the disk. As a troubleshooting tool, it does not have many settings.

Comment: That's a shame, seems like it should be an option.  Feel free to add your comment as an answer so I can accept it.

Comment: How did you create such rule? I've just tried to reproduce (crash rule - specific iis application pool) and id didn't create a dump on recycle event.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Copied from the comment.

Debug Diag is a troubleshooting tool, so it does not have too many options to configure. Generally speaking you should disable the rule as soon as possible.

But if you need to live it enabled, then your only chance is to set a limit on user dump count, and then manually remove useless dumps from the disk to clean up space. More information on user dump count configuration can be found in [this article](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/asiatech/2014/01/09/debug-diagnostic-2-0-creating-a-rule-in-crash-mode/).